# SonarCloud code smell when I convert byte[] to String with String constructor

Tags: java, base64

This is my function that decodes a JWT Object to String:

```
protected String decodeJWT(String idToken){

    String[] splitString = idToken.split("\\.");
    String base64EncodedBody = splitString[1];
    
    Base64 base64Url = new Base64(true);
    String idTokenString = new String(base64Url.decode(base64EncodedBody));
    StringBuilder sub = new StringBuilder();
    
    int indexStart = idTokenString.indexOf("\"sub\":\"") + 7;
    char c;
    while((c = idTokenString.charAt(indexStart)) != '\"') {
        indexStart++;
        sub.append(c);
    }
    
    return sub.toString();
}
```

SonarCloud detect a code smell when I convert `base64Url.decode(base64EncodedBody)`, that is a `byte[]`, on a `String`.
This is the issue:

> Constructors should not be used to instantiate "String",
> "BigInteger", "BigDecimal" and primitive-wrapper classes.

> Constructors for String, BigInteger, BigDecimal and the objects used to wrap
> primitives should never be used. Doing so is less clear and uses more
> memory than simply using the desired value in the case of strings, and
> using valueOf for everything else.

How can I resolve this code smell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this constructor

`String(byte bytes[], Charset charset)` constructor instead

hence code can be changed as

```
String s = new String(base64Url.decode(base64EncodedBody), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

refer https://gazelle.ihe.net/sonar/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS1943&rule_key=squid%3AS1943

> String constructors with a byte[] argument but no Charset argument is
> a minor code smell